# Create a List of byte[]

Tags: java

How might you go about creating a List of `byte[]` (not `Byte`)?

I want something like the following:

```
byte[] deb = new byte[Byte.MIN_VALUE];
List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<>();
begin.add(deb);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Any issues?

Comment: when you said `note Byte` did you mean **not** Byte` ? or it's just emphasis

Comment: OK, your code should create list of byte arrays and add there one element. What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That will work fine because **arrays are objects** in Java, so you can build `List`s out of them.

---

Note that only in Java 7 can you do

```
List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<>();
```

In older versions you must restate the `byte[]`:

```
List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
```

---

This has been brought up already but I'll just reiterate it here. `Byte.MIN_VALUE` is less than `0`; you cannot create an array of length less than `0` (it results in a runtime error, specifically a `NegativeArraySizeException`). Did you mean `Byte.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: Why do you mention `assuming you're using Java 7 (<>)`? What's the difference between Java 7 and Java 6 here?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Perhaps I should have made this more clear. In Java 6 you must do `List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<byte[]>()`, but in Java 7 you can simply do `List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at below line

```
 byte[] deb = new byte[Byte.MIN_VALUE]; <---Byte.MIN_VALUE -127
```

You should declare your array with positive values Other wise you get **NegativeArraySizeException**.

```
byte[] deb = new byte[Some positive value];
```

`Byte.MIN_VALUE` is `-127`. You can not create negative index array in java.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are objects. byte[] is an array which holds byte values. collections accept objects, thus List is a collection which holds byte[]. 
your code should work without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Byte.MIN_VALUE` is `-128`. If you try to create an array with negative length, you will get an error.

Second, as mentioned in other answers, the code to create the List should be

```
List<byte[]> begin = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
```

Comment: The second part only applies to anything before Java 7. In Java 7 the diamond operator works just fine here.

Comment: True, however, we do not know if Java 7 is used.